# Phrases to give home address

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, idiomatic-language

Whether it's a phone call for technical support, home service or delivery, you'd need to give the person on the other end your home address. (Often it's one of the first pieces of information you give following 'Hi, my name is XXX) What are some formal and idiomatic ways to do it? Ones I often use are:

1. I live at XXX road
2. My home address is XXX road
3. I am the resident of XXX road

The first two are pretty common and simplistic. The third has a nice ring to it, but I am not sure if it's grammatical to use the word 'resident' for a specific address as opposed to a general city/town. 
What are some alternative expressions for this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "My address is ..." is enough. You don't need to say more since it is the address you want something sent to or done at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the simplest way to say something is the best way -- although it can also be boring! If ***I live at 123 Main Street*** and ***My home address is 123 Main Street*** isn't satisfying to you, there are a few wordier options.

***I am the resident of 123 Main Street*** sounds a little too formal and might confuse the person you're talking to. There is a question of whether you are "*the* resident" or "*a* resident," which is more info than they need to know anyway. Instead, you could say ***I reside at*** (not "of"), or ***We've taken up residence at***. It's probably as sophisticated as you need to be -- or should be -- when talking to tech support or a delivery person.

You could say ***We call home 123 Main Street.*** If you want to get fancy with idioms, you could say ***I hang my hat at 123 Main Street*** or ***My humble abode is located at 123 Main Street***. Native speakers will understand you, and they might think you are friendly and awesome.